# In angularjs, how to use controller's method in custom directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In the javascript file, the code is like this:

```
angular.module("amodule")
  .directive("bdirective",function(){
    return{
      scope: {
        testIsolated: '&test',
      },
      restrict:'EA',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: "address.html",
    }
  .controller{"ccontroller",function($scope){

    $scope.test=function(){
                           w="changed"
                           return w;
                          };
    };
```

In the `index.html` file, the code is like this:

```
<bdirective testIsolated="test()"></bdirective>
...
```

In the `address.html` file, the code is like this:

```
<button ng-click="result=testIsolated()">Button1</button>
...
```

I think when the Button1 is clicked, testIsolated should run, and then `test()` should run. The value of `"result"` should be changed to `"changed"`.

But it doesn't work

Can anyone help me figure it out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello. This seems like a useful question but the language is a little vague - it's hard to pick up at a glance what issue you are having, could you tweak this question to focus on the issue, maybe add a bold one line statement outlining what you'd like clear up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have worked if you:

**#1** either changed the attribute to `test`:

```
<bdirective test="test()"></bdirective>
```

Or, **#2** changed how your isolate scope binding was defined:

```
scope: {
   testIsolated: "&"
}
```

and the attribute was hyphenated to `test-isolated` due to how Angular normalizes attributes:

```
<bdirective test-isolated="test()"></bdirective>
```

Comment: Thx. how should I call the test() method in address.html?

Comment: @Bluesea, exactly like you do right now... you just have a mismatch between between the attribute of `bdirective` and the bound scope variable

Comment: @Bluesea, here's a demo with approach #1: http://plnkr.co/edit/IN3XbWtRPFRZf1fKZDli?p=preview. It's the same as your code with minor fixes

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you can make test() have an argument in the Demo. For example: $scope.test=function(date){ var w="Today is"+date; return w; }.

Comment: @Bluesea, this is really a different question -  a question about how to pass local variables into the bound expressions - and should have been asked separately. Anyway, this is how it can be done: http://plnkr.co/edit/OnRED9iekq9g0lYd2kps?p=preview

Comment: @Bluesea, if it resolved your issue, consider accepting